# Where to geographically create and how to make azure redis cache perform when traffic comes from all over the world?

Tags: azure, scaling, azure-redis-cache, azure-traffic-manager

Been looking for a way to have my azure redis cache behave pretty much like the web apps and traffic manager. I.e. Route the request to the nearest cache instance depending on where you are in the world.

I have one azure redis cache but i want to have many of these replicated. I can upscale but it all seems to be sat on one server which you define when you create the cache.

Basically, how do i create an azure redis cache and have it serve traffic from opposite ends of the earth just as fast?

Comment: Redis isn't something you'd directly expose to your end-users; that is, they're not going to open a web page (or download content) directly from Redis, as they would with  web app. Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: Users are exposed to a web blade closest to their location. However, I want my blade to then go to its nearest redis cache. No point having web blades close to certain locations if it falls back onto a cache located across the world.